# Hibernate : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: java, hibernate, casting, classcastexception

My Staff Entity defined in Java is like this :

```
final public class Staff {
    private int staffId;
    private String firstName = null;
    private String lastName = null;
    private String Email = null;
    private double salary;
    //and the setters and getters
}
```

My Query code :

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Staff staff = null;
try {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(dto.Staff.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("salary", 1000000));
    staff = (Staff) criteria.uniqueResult();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error : " + e);
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

But when I run this I get an error which says :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

If I explicitly cast the number to a double it works :

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("salary", (double) 1000000));
```

Is there any way to do this without the explicit casting? 
Also I thought that in Java, Integer to Double conversion was Implicit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate considering it as a integer, tell that  it's double.

```
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("salary",   1000000d));
```

Comment: But I haven't used Wrapper classes anywhere

Comment: Is there any way I could add the 'd' to the number dynamically? Because I am trying to write a function which is supposed to set any type of restriction. In fact it could be an integer or a string. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes.  You could write `new Double(xxx.toString())` - this will do the right thing whether `xxx` is a `Double`, an `Integer`, a `String` or basically anything that can reasonably be converted to a `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

The restriction.eq takes an object, so no implicit casting is possible.